# Validate and Load JSON data from a file

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to load all student entities from a file containing either a single or array of JSON representation of Student data.
If schema for Student entity is static, then I can use:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Student> studentList = mapper.readValue( file, Student.class );
```

Above code gets all valid student entries.

But if schema for Student entity does not have a pre-defined class and is loaded as a JSON file which can be updated dynamically, then how can we get list of student entries from file?

--Update--
Student schema is stored in a column in Schema table as follows:

```
{ 
 "name":"...",
 "age":?
}
```

User uploads a file, having array of student JSON entries:

```
[{
  "name":"Abc",
  "age":10
},
{
  "name":"Def",
  "age":15
}]
```

In Backend, I should read this file and compare json structure with schema defined for Student in Schema table, If it matches, then it is valid student JSON which I need to store it in Student table as JSON.

Now admin can come in and update schema for student, Example:

```
{ 
 "name":"...",
 "age":?,
 "gender":".."
},
```

So that next time when user uploads file containing student data, it has to be validated against above schema and saved.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. If the JSON is completely open and editable then there is no way you can do anything with it. What if I call the student names as 'eman' in the JSON? You should impose some structure to the JSON for being able to read and use it.

Comment: Take a look into http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Comment: @Abhishek What happens to the `gender` field after the admin adds `gender` field to the JSON? Do you want to consider that or ignore it?

Comment: @RaviH: For existing student entries, It wont affect, But on uploading new student entries, It will check if gender field is present in JSON or not, If present save in student table data column as json stringified format else ignore

Comment: @Abhishek Do you have the list of all possible fields that can some in later?  Who and how the table will be updated later to include the new fields that can come in? Where is the mapping from the JSON fields that may come in later to the database table column names? You are opening up a can of worms by accepting such a requirement.

Comment: @RaviH First of all, schema for Student entity is stored in Schema table as JSON and even student entries which are sent from client in a file are stored as JSON (stringified format) in Student table. Student table has only one column called data which holds JSON of a specific student. So if there are array of 'n' JSON objects sent in a file each representing a student, then 'n' number of entries have to be made in Student table where each row's data column holds JSON string for a student.
So all new fields that come in for a schema will be modified in data column of Schema table

Comment: @Abhishek This will bring up lot of difficulties in a real application to be really used by people. Proceed carefully is all I can say. This is not the best way to store data if your target is a RDBMS. You should be still ok if you use a document data store. However, you will have to identify a unique identifier in each student record to be able to retrieve, update or delete it later.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

You can do something like -

```
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("json string");
System.out.println(jsonObj.get("studentName or some field"));
```

Comment: Well, yes, you'll have to cast the fields later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jackson, then you could use trees rather than POJOs - this copes well with dynamic models. You work with `ObjectNode`s.

Jumping on point:

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"...\",\"age\":18,\"gender\":\"..\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode tree = (ObjectNode)mapper.readTree(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read it into a Jackson JsonNode object as shown below. It gives you a tree like structure with each node as a JsonNode.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(jsonData, JsonNode.class);
```

Then, use findValue() to get the desired property node as shown below:

```
JsonNode node = rootNode.findValue(propertyName);
```

You can retrieve the node value node.longValue() or node.intValue() or node.booleanValue() etc.